# How to ignore certain words or characters whilst using setSpan

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

Given that we have returned separately a list of animals:

```
val animals = "cat, dog and mouse"
```

Which we then concat to our `animalsMessage` so it looks as following:

```
val animalsMessage = "You have identified cat, dog and mouse"
```

Given my default font colour is white and I only wanted to change the `val animals` font colour in my `animalsMessage`, I could do:

```
animalsMessage.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow, null)),
        animalsMessage.length - animals.length,
        animalsMessage.length,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
```

However, say I wanted to ignore the `,` and the word `and` whilst spanning, so they remained the default white colour, how would I go about doing that? I am basing this question on the assumption that there might be an `and` in the animals string and there might be one `,` or many.

I believe the answer lies in using a pattern matcher and then ignoring whilst spanning based on finding a match.

Things I have tried:

First, before concat my `val animals` to my `val animalsMessage` I tried to format my `val animals` as described above, to do that, I created the below method:

```
private fun ignoreSeparators(animals: String): SpannableString {
    val spannable = SpannableString(animals)
    val matcher: Matcher = Pattern.compile(",\\\\and").matcher(animals)
    while (!matcher.matches()) {
        val animal = matcher.group(1)
        val animalIndex: Int = animals?.indexOf(animal) - 1
        spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow, null)), 0, animalIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
    return spannable
}
```

I then planned on returning the spanned text and then concating it to my `val animalsMessage`, however, I get a crash saying that no match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing the following, first, remove the `,` and `and` change to a list as follows...

```
 val animals = listOf("cat", "dog", "mouse")
```

Then, pass them to the following method that will handle the styling, followed by adding the necessary `comma` and the `and`. The rule followed was that the `and` would always be between the last and second from last animal and all other values no matter how large the list is, would be separated by a comma.

The second param, prefix, is simply our `animalsMessage` which we concat to, as mentioned in your question.

```
private fun formatAnimalStrings(animals: List<String>, prefix: String): SpannableStringBuilder {
        val lastIndex = animals.size - 1
        val secondLastIndex = lastIndex - 1
        val result = SpannableStringBuilder(prefix)
        animals.forEachIndexed { index, animal ->
            val startIndex = result.length
            result.append(animals[index])
            result.setSpan(
                ForegroundColorSpan(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow, null)),
                startIndex,
                startIndex + animal.length,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
            if (index < lastIndex) {
                if (index == secondLastIndex) {
                    result.append(" and ")
                } else {
                    result.append(", ")
                }
            }
        }
        result.append(".")
        return result
    }
```

This would result in

> You have identified **cat**, **dog** and **mouse**

(I have used bold to express yellow text colour, since I cannot make the text yellow)